# In satchmo, How to display price in featured products, home page and category page of products

Tags: satchmo

I used

```
{% if sale %}
    <strike id="fullprice" style="display: block;">
        {{ product|discount_price:""|currency }}
    </strike>
{% endif %}
<span id="price">{{ product|discount_price:sale|currency }}</span>
```

This works without **sale** i.e., discount_price:**sale**|currency and throws an exception

> Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key
>   [sale] in ...

Its important that both sale price and non sale price is displayed. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use individual sale assigned by product, you should use

```
{{ product|sale_price|currency }}
```

or you can replace `sale_price` by `taxed_sale_price` or `untaxed_sale_price` if you want set one explicit e.g. on invoices.

If you mean a discount for whole site, e.g. to create a special discount for the logged user, you should use 
`discount_price:storewide_sale` because this "sale" variable created by context processor has been renamed to storewide_sale at the request of several users.

Comment: thank you that worked. I was already using {{ product|sale_price|currency}} but I am wondering why would {{ product|discount_price:sale|currency }} work in the product.html file... found under product/templates/product.html and not when used in homepage or category page... btw, I did load all the required template tags.

Comment: thank you for your help, but this worked only to a certain extent... I want to display the actual price strike out for only products which have the discount using if condition like {% if storewide_sale %} or which ever applies then strik out the actual price and show sale price... but this does not seem to happen on featured page.

Comment: I just achieved this by using `{% if product|discount_saved:storewide_sale %}` can you confirm if this correct way of doing it! Thank you.